# Keeping non-ASCII characters in folder and file names between Mac and Windows

Tags: windows-10, mac, character-encoding

When I create folders with en- or em-dashes on a Mac, I'd like for them to still be the same when I hand them to my friend who has a Windows 10 PC.  When I create them, this is how they look on my machine:

[image]

I then zip up the folders using the built-in ***Compress*** utility (when you right-click a folder) and email them to him, however, once he unzips the folders using ***Winzip***, then they look like this on his Windows 10 machine:

[image]

I'm at a loss at to what's going on...can anyone offer a suggestion as to how I can send my friend the folders and keep the file name integrity?  Maybe my Mac is UTF-8 and his encoding is Windows-1252?  Maybe his zip utility is encoding differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a forward slash in file/folder names in Windows. See this more more information:

[How can I create files on Windows with embedded slashes, using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10708449/7686957)

It is an encoding issue. When you extract, the zip program writes the file/folder name in the exact same encoding it was compressed in which mangles the file/folder names. I'm currently not sure if there's a solution to it.

Comment: Thanks @Philip Gibbons, when I sent the folders to my friend via a fileshare, they looked fine.  It must be something to do with the zip program as you mentioned.  If you ever figure out how to unzip using UTF-8 encoding, please edit your answer in the future...thanks!